# Two conditions have to be true then be counted

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm working on a spreadsheet that two conditions have to true in order to be counted.  If the month is January, and the number next to it is less than or equal to 30, then it's counted.  Same rule applies for all the other months.

Thus far, I have:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!D2:D7,(SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(D2:D7)=1))),Sheet1!E2:E7,(COUNTIFS(E2:E7,"<=30")))
```

For example:

```
Column D
Jan 1, 2014
Feb 3, 2014
Feb 16, 2014
Mar 5, 2014
Mar 13, 2014
Mar 29, 2014

Column E
37
25
30
31
1
16

Outcome
Jan 0
Feb 2
Mar 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy. Try this:

```
{=SUM(IF(MONTH($D$2:$D$7)=1,1,0)*IF($E$2:$E$7<=30,1,0))}
```

Of course you can replace the `=1` part with a reference to a cell with the month number or even `=MONTH(H2)`, for example, given a cell with a date in it so you can build your formula as a table.

Note: the only trick to this is that the formula must be entered as an array formula. So do <kbd>CNTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when entering in the formula.